# How to customize start time value and add some text to amCharts balloons

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am stuck at trying to format values for `startTime` & `endTime` fields as time. I want the format to be like **05:00** or **17:10** also to add a custom text on top of every serial.

[Example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hdt043dt/)

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "theme": "light",
  "type": "serial",
  "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "name": "111",
    "startTime": 7.00,
    "endTime": 17.0,
    "value1": "2016-05-03",
    "value2": "2016-05-05",
    "color": "#FF3F33",

  }, {
    "name": "220",
    "startTime": 18.17,
    "endTime": 16.18,
    "value1": "2016-03-15",
    "value2": "2016-03-20",
    "color": "#FFB134",

  }, {
    "name": "109",
    "startTime": 17.0,
    "endTime": 18.40,
    "value1": "2016-01-20",
    "value2": "2016-01-22",
    "color": "#F9FF34",

  }, {
    "name": "108",
    "startTime": 19,
    "endTime": 21,
    "value1": "2016-01-20",
    "value2": "2016-01-21",
    "color": "#36DB44",

  }, {
    "name": "107",
    "startTime": 14.50,
    "endTime": 16.30,
    "value1": "2016-01-20",
    "value2": "2016-01-22",
    "color": "#9DC481",

  }, {
    "name": "106",
    "startTime": 5.50,
    "endTime": 9.15,
    "value1": "2016-02-02",
    "value2": "2016-02-05",
    "color": "#D66C6E",

  }, {
    "name": "105",
    "startTime": 6,
    "endTime": 8,
    "value1": "2016-01-13",
    "value2": "2016-01-21",
    "color": "#0D8ECF",

  }, {
    "name": "104",
    "startTime": 5,
    "endTime": 8,
    "value1": "2016-01-28",
    "value2": "2016-01-31",
    "color": "#FF3F33",

  }, {
    "name": "103",
    "startTime": 5.30,
    "endTime": 7.30,
    "value1": "2016-01-27",
    "value2": "2016-01-31",
    "color": "#FFB134",

  }, {
    "name": "102",
    "startTime": 9,
    "endTime": 11,
    "value1": "2016-01-20",
    "value2": "2016-01-25",
    "color": "#F9FF34",

  }, {
    "name": "101",
    "startTime": 10.0,
    "endTime": 11,
    "value1": "2016-01-22",
    "value2": "2016-01-23",
    "color": "#36DB44",

  } ],
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "gridAlpha": 0.1
  } ],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [ {
    //"valueField": "value",
    "balloonText": "<b>Flight Number [[category]]</b><br>Schedule start date: [[value1]]<br>Schedule end date: [[value2]]<br> Departure Time: [[startTime]]<br> Arrival Time: [[endTime]]",
    "colorField": "color",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "openField": "startTime",
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "endTime",
  } ],
  "chartCursor": {
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false,
    "valueZoomable": true
  },
  "rotate": true,
  "columnWidth": 1,
  "categoryField": "name",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "gridAlpha": 0.1,
    "position": "left"
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "valueScrollbar": {

  }
} );
```

I'm trying to learn some customization tricks, if you have any referral link please paste it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`balloonFunction`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#balloonFunction) for that. It allows setting a custom function that would format balloon contents according to your logic, including formatting proprietary values as time:

```
"graphs": [ {
  //"valueField": "value",
  "balloonFunction": function( item ) {

    function formatTime( val ) {
      var minutes = Math.round( val * 60 );
      var hours = Math.floor( minutes / 60 );
      minutes = minutes - hours * 60;
      var str = String( hours );
      str += ":" + ( minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes );
      return str;
    }

    var text = "<b>Flight Number " + item.category + 
               "</b><br>Schedule start date: " + item.dataContext.value1 + 
               "<br>Schedule end date: " + item.dataContext.value1 + 
               "<br> Departure Time: " + formatTime( item.dataContext.startTime ) + 
               "<br> Arrival Time: " + formatTime( item.dataContext.endTime );
    return text;
  },
  "colorField": "color",
  "fillAlphas": 0.8,
  "lineAlpha": 0,
  "openField": "startTime",
  "type": "column",
  "valueField": "endTime",
} ]
```

To display some custom information directly over the bars, use graph settings [`labelText`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#labelText) and [`labelPosition`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#labelPosition). I.e.:

```
"labelText": "[[customText]]",
"labelPosition": "middle"
```

"[[customText]]" will refer to a field in your data and display it's contents over the bar, if present.

Here's your [fiddle with the above update](https://jsfiddle.net/hdt043dt/3/).

Comment: thanks. what about adding a custom text on top of each item @martynasma

Comment: Updated my answer per your additional question.